# Free Code Camp weather app, toggle won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my Javascript code.

```
$("#changetemp").click(function () {
    var temp = $("#temperature").html;
    var final_letter = temp[temp.length-1];
$("#temperature").html(function () 
        {if (final_letter == "F") {return celsius;} 
         else {return fahrenheit;}});});

});}});});
```

It is supposed to toggle the temperature between celsius and fahrenheit but does a big fat nothing. I've googled and changed a few things (e.g. gone between val, html and text, and tried charAt but I can't get it to do anything, let alone the right thing. Any suggestions would be very welcome.

Edit: "#changetemp" is the button you click to toggle between temperature (ideally). 
"#temperature" is where the temperature displays (and it does, but then won't change).

Also tried:

- console.log(final_letter); (which gave the correct letter in the console)

  - console.log(celsius); (which reports as 'undefined') as does console.log(fahrenheit);

These two are defined earlier via a JSON 
    $.getJSON( url, function(location){ var celsius = 
    $("#temperature").html(Math.round(location.main.temp - 273) + "°C");});

and I tried to make them be global variables by putting

var celsius; 
var fahrenheit;

after the beginning of the first function (which surrounds everything else) but I'm guessing that didn't work.

More:

Googling suggests that variables cannot begin with a number. Is this what is stopping me here?
 1. I've managed to show the temperature though, just not change it. 
 2. How do you get round that? I tried changing the code so that 'celsius' would give 'Temperature: 10C' rather than '10C' but that didn't solve it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, please have a read of the [tour] and [ask].  Also have a look at [mcve] - specifically the *complete* part.  In this case, some HTML would help as we don't know what `#changetemp` refers to.  It would also help if you can reduce the code to the *minimal* required to reproduce this issue.  You can also use a 'snippet' to add code and show it (not-)working.

Comment: Hope that's improved it.

Comment: As @steeno said - it should be `.html()` - add `var temp = $("#temperature").html(); console.log(temp);` to see exactly what it's giving you.

Comment: Please add some html, specifically for what sort of node `#temperature` refers to.  If it's a `div``span``td` then use `.text()` - if it's an input (eg `<input type='text' id='temperature'/>`) then use `.val()`

Comment: Done console.log(temp); and the correct temperature in F appears in the console. 

The temperature for what #temperature refers to is <div id = "temperature"></div>

Answer (score 0):

i assume the error is in the line `var temp = $("#temperature").html;`
Does it help if you change it to `var temp = $("#temperature").html();`?
html is a jQuery function, so you need to call it with the parantheses. Otherwise temp will not contain the content of the #temp element, but rather a reference to the html method. Therefore you don't get the last letter of the content.

Comment: Thanks @steeno. Tried that but still no joy. 

I have wondered whether I should be using val, html or text or whether it perhaps doesn't matter. Have tried all 3 and googling about each but none works.

Comment: In this case do what freedomn-m suggested and add an `alert(temp);` or `console.log(temp);` after the `var temp = ....` line. Just to be sure what the variable `temp` contains. If you use the console.log version you can press F12 (mostly in all browsers) to open the developer tools of the browser. You can see the console.log output (or f.e. javascript errors) in the developer tools console window.

Comment: Just wanted to add: thank you for your kindness to a newbie. I changed to using a var count with different functions on odd and even clicks and have managed to make it work.